# Sort point coordinates in serpentine pattern

Tags: c++, sorting, coordinates

In my code, I calculate the intersections of two straight. The points of intersection, where they exist, are saved in a vector. This vector is now to be sorted so that a serpentine-like structure forms. To explain here once the current output of my function:

```
-2.8    -3.5
-2.6    -3.5
 3.1    -3.5
-3.8    -2.5
-3.6    -2.5
 3.8    -2.5
 4      -2.5
-4.3    -1.4
 4.4    -1.4
-4.5    -0.5
 4.6    -0.5
 4.7    -0.5
-4.5     0.5
 4.6     0.5
 4.7     0.5
-4.2     1.5
 4.4     1.5
-3.8     2.5
-3.6     2.5
 3.8     2.5
 3.9     2.5
 4       2.5
 2.9     3.5
 3.1     3.5
-2.8     3.5
```

The second column may already be sorted in ascending order, but now the first column must be sorted so that they will once sorted in ascending and descending again.
The expected output should look like this:

```
-2.8    -3.5
-2.6    -3.5
 3.1    -3.5
 4      -2.5
 3.8    -2.5
-3.6    -2.5
-3.8    -2.5
-4.3    -1.4
 4.4    -1.4
 4.7    -0.5
 4.6    -0.5
-4.5    -0.5
-4.5     0.5
 4.6     0.5
 4.7     0.5
 4.4     1.5
-4.2     1.5
-3.8     2.5
-3.6     2.5
 3.8     2.5
 3.9     2.5
 4       2.5
 3.1     3.5
 2.9     3.5
-2.8     3.5
```

The acutual output looks like this:

```
 3.1    -3.5
-2.6    -3.5
-2.8    -3.5
-3.8    -2.5
-3.6    -2.5
 3.8    -2.5
 4      -2.5
 4.4    -1.4
-4.3    -1.4
-4.5    -0.5
 4.6    -0.5
 4.7    -0.5
 4.7     0.5
 4.6     0.5
-4.5     0.5
-4.2     1.5
 4.4     1.5
 4       2.5
 3.9     2.5
 3.8     2.5
-3.6     2.5
-3.8     2.5
 2.9     3.5
 3.1     3.5
-2.8     3.5
```

My first attempt looked like this

```
bool ascending_first = false;
auto firstInRange = intersects.begin();

while(firstInRange != intersects.end()) {
    auto endInRange = 
    adjacent_find(firstInRange, intersects.end(), [](const std::array<double, 3>& a, const std::array<double, 3>& b) 
        {return a[1] != b[1]; });

    if (endInRange != intersects.end()) ++endInRange;
    std::sort(firstInRange, endInRange, [ascending_first](const std::array<double, 3>& a, const std::array<double, 3>& b)
        {return ascending_first ? a[0] < b[0] : b[0] < a[0] ;});

    ascending_first = ! ascending_first;
    firstInRange = endInRange;
}
```

The problem with this code is that it only works when exactly two points are provided with the same y-coordinate. If more intersections with the same y coordinate found the serpentine pattern is not created correctly.
Can anyone give a tip on how I still can achieve the desired result?

**Edit:** I just checked my code again. And I've seen that not the sort function is the problem. Since I have only numbers with one decimal place, I round the double values. For this I used the floor function.

```
for(size_t b=0; b<intersects.size(); b++)
{
    intersects[b][0]=intersects[b][0]*10;
    intersects[b][1]=intersects[b][1]*10;
    intersects[b][2]=intersects[b][2]*10;

    intersects[b][0]=floor(intersects[b][0]);
    intersects[b][1]=floor(intersects[b][1]);
    intersects[b][2]=floor(intersects[b][2]);

    intersects[b][0]=intersects[b][0]/10;
    intersects[b][1]=intersects[b][1]/10;
    intersects[b][2]=intersects[b][2]/10;
}
```

Here, however, it seems to be the case that the decimal not match exactly. My approach to this extract corpses it would be the sort function to expand the possibility of a range. It takes the sort function to a `±0.1` to be extended. but I'm not sure how I can do with my code.

Comment: Could you provide expected output ? (Can multiple output be possible ?)

Comment: Your code provide correct output for the sample (inverting initial value of `ascending_first`) [Demo](http://ideone.com/zyR72X), So can you provide example for which you don't have expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef pair<float, float> pff;
std::vector<pff> vp{
    {-2.6, -3.5}, {-2.8, -3.5}, {3.1, -3.5},  {-3.8, -2.5}, {-3.6, -2.5},
    {3.8, -2.5},  {4, -2.5},    {-4.3, -1.4}, {4.4, -1.4},  {-4.5, -0.5},
    {4.6, -0.5},  {4.7, -0.5},  {-4.5, 0.5},  {4.6, 0.5},   {4.7, 0.5},
    {-4.2, 1.5},  {4.4, 1.5},   {-3.8, 2.5},  {-3.6, 2.5},  {3.8, 2.5},
    {3.9, 2.5},   {4, 2.5},     {2.9, 3.5},   {3.1, 3.5},   {-2.8, 3.5}};

template <class T>
struct xx_than_key
{
    inline bool operator() (const pff &a, const pff &b) const
    {
        return T()(a.first, b.first);
    }
};

void sort()
{
    auto c = vp.begin();
    int b = true;
    for (auto p = vp.begin(); p < vp.end(); ++p)
    {
        if (p->second != c->second)
        {
            if (b)
            {
                std::sort(c, p, xx_than_key<std::less<float>>());
            }
            else
            {
                std::sort(c, p, xx_than_key<std::greater<float>>());
            }
            b = !b;
            c = p;
        }
    }
}
```